# CSS Sprites not hover over action performing

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, css-sprites

i was looking around and i saw a very technical navigation, its pretty awesome for me. when i read its codes i got stucked. i tried all my best but unable to understand please help me.

> http://jsfiddle.net/RXvyY/

i tried many timese to make this navigation same as orignal but i don't whats wrong with me. please help me to solve ... when i hover over the navigation button it doesn't change.. and when i click there is no possibility the it changed...

the orignal navigation link is ... where is saw it first.

> http://www.intuit.com/

please help me.

Comment: My super-paranoia is tingling...

Comment: what? i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this part of the css:

```
.primary-level a {
    display:block;
    height: 80px;
    background:url("http://www.intuit.com/sbweb/common/includes/header/navigation/images/nav_main.png") no-repeat;
}
```

you were changing the background position for the links on hover but the links didn't actually have a background set. The `height` is so there is a target for the link - you can change it to whatever you want. I have set it at the height of the entire menu but you may only want half of that.

EDIT:

you could add this:

```
#nav-primary-intuit a:active{
     background-position: -9px -220px;
}
```

you'll have to add it for each menu item, of course

EDIT 2:

how about this then...

change your css to this:

```
#nav-primary-intuit a.active {
    background-position: -9px -220px;
}
```

note that `active` is now a class not a pseudo-class

add this jquery:

```
$("a").bind({
    click: function () {
        $("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

the `removeClass` takes the `active` class away from all links then it adds it back to the selected one

Comment: agreed ... almost problem solved but i want when i click on sum buttom its changes to 3rd menu.. you can see that menu `http://www.intuit.com/sbweb/common/includes/header/navigation/images/nav_main.png`  and thanks alot

Comment: its working. but when i click on any button just. and when i just remove my cursor from the navigation old state came back.

Comment: `http://jsfiddle.net/RXvyY/2/` well i tried this . but when i click on first button, it keep remain checked and when i click another button it also same... i want when i click home other buttons stay normal and when i click anyother button all others remain normal..

Comment: i think there must be some jquery stuff